# Bottom to top layout desing for chat application

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

I am designing a webapp for chat application. I have an API which returns a list of messages:

```
chatsite.com/api/thread/1/messages/

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sender": {
            "id": 2,
            "email": "usertwo@gmail.com"
        },
        "sent_datetime": "2017-09-06T17:31:30Z",
        "body": "user two sending a message in new thread (pk1)"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "sender": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "user@gmail.com"
        },
        "sent_datetime": "2017-09-06T17:28:56Z",
        "body": "Nwe thread est body"
    }
]
```

This is how the html is layout for now:

```
<div id="Thread">
    <div id="Header"></div>
    <div id="MessageList">
        <div class="message">
            <p>{{message.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <p>{{message.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <p>{{message.body}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
```

And its related css:

```
#Thread {
    background-color: mediumseagreen;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 600px;
}

#Header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

#MessageList {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.message {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 4px;
}

#Footer {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

As of now all, the messages are ordered by the latest message in a Top to Bottom fashion. Latest being on the top, and so on :

```
__________________
|                |
|     HEADER     |
|________________|
|                |
| Latest msg     |
|________________|
|                |
| 2nd latest msg |
|________________|
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|
|                |
|     FOOTER     |
|________________|
```

But I would like to get the messages in Bottom to Top way like all the messaging platform are these days. Latest being on the bottom an so on:

```
__________________
|                |
|     HEADER     |
|________________|
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|
|                |
| 2nd latest msg |
|________________|
|                |
| Latest msg     |
|________________|
|                |
|     FOOTER     |
|________________|
```

If it helps, I am using Vuejs as the frontend framework.

Comment: Can you order the result from the API?

Comment: Can't you simply use `flex-direction: column-reverse`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
#MessageList {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

to

```
#MessageList {
    flex-direction: column-reverse; /* this */
}
```

```css
#Thread {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

#Header {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#MessageList {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.message {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 4px;
}

#Footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="Thread">
  <div id="Header"></div>
  <div id="MessageList">
    <div class="message">
      <p>Latest</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Older</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>Oldest</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the flow and also the scrollbar to keep last message at bottom of the container. CSS used : `flex-direction:column-reverse; transform:scale(1,-1);`

because of a bug, `flex-direction:column` + `flex:1` + **`overflow:auto` not working**, i added an extra wrapper to get an efficient scrollbar to scroll to the older message if you want to. Last being shown at the bottom against the footer.

example

```js
// demo purposefaking new messsage coming up .. nop down the list ;)
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#buffer").append('<div class="message"><p>The latest message added to the list.<br/>'+Date()+'</p></div>');
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#Thread {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 600px;
  max-height: 100vh;/* added optionnal*/
}

#Header, #Footer {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  line-height:2em;
  color:white;;
}

#MessageList {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  flex: 1;/* added */
  transform: scale(1, -1);/* added  mirror the box and the scrollbar*/
  overflow: auto;/* added */
}

#buffer {
  display: flex;/* added */
  flex-flow: column-reverse;/* added */
  counter-reset: msg/* added */
}

.message:before {
  content: 'message N°'counter(msg);/* added */
  color:purple;
}
.message:nth-child(odd):before{
  color:lime
}

.message {
  counter-increment: msg;/* added */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 4px;
  transform: scale(1, -1)/* added make the message readable again */
}

#Footer {
  background: red;
}
body {margin:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Thread">
  <div id="Header">header any height</div>
  <div id="MessageList">
    <div id="buffer">
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="message">
        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="Footer">footer any height</div>
</div>
```

[pen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gGbpLY)

Comment: Cool, but if you scroll it using mouse wheel, it is scrolled in the opposite direction :)

Comment: @Qwertiy yes it does, takes 10th of a second to scroll opposite, not an issue to me when most of people do not even notices it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function () {
  var main = document.querySelector('main');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = Date();
  main.appendChild(div);
  main.scrollTop = main.scrollHeight; // Yep, it's larger, but browser will handle that
}, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background: antiquewhite;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main::before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<main></main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```